# Name object automatically and show their properties when chosen

Tags: c#, object

I've just got a stupid question. I have done research but I quite don't understand the explanations given as I'm a beginner in C#.
I have a class called things. The user now ca create a new object in this class by clicking a button. He can give some propertes for the object before, e.g. a description or a name.
This new object has to be created automatically then.
I want a list where all the object names are listed and when the user clicks on one of these, a label should show other properties of the object apart from the name, e.g. the description.
How shall I name these objects the user creates? And how can I make the label show the properties when the user just clicks on the list.

The program has no use really but I want to create it in order to learn how object orientation works.

I hope you understand my question.

Thanks in advance to everybody

Comment: what should be the name of the object? are you talking about the name of the type? that aside this doesn't seem to be an application that servers well for understanding OO since there's no OO concepts in it. What's the user mental model you are trying to model?

Comment: I tried to create the object first with a standaard name and then rename it using the name given by the user. But that didn't work out and I have no idea how I can call for the properties with such a naming procedure. I tried it with dictionaries, but i didn't understand that right, i guess. I have no idea how to show the properties of the object when chosen in the list even if i named it with a dictionary. I don't want ready code, I just want to understand the basic principle how one can use object automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my assumption,

You have a Class named "SomeClass", When you click "New" Button, the new object should be created and it should be added to the list.

You can have a `List<SomeClass> list = new List<SomeClass>()` Which will act as a main list, and you can just use the single object as follows,

ON NEW OBJECT CLICK

```
SomeClass cls = new SomeClass();
cls.Description ="desc";
list.Add(cls)
```

Hope this is what you are expecting.

Comment: thank you but what if the user creates another object now? wouldn't that be called cls again then? (I hope the question is not tooo stupid).

Comment: Yes. It will be created and instance will be added to the main list. You can make "cls" declaration global. In any case, object will be newly created every time.

Comment: and how are you gonna distinguish between them? How can you call them seperatly?

Comment: First you try and see. Don't ask too much unnecessary questions. U must know programming first to understand this.

Comment: How can I program it without having understood it?

Comment: Thanks toRajesh, your idea brought me on the right track